# If $X \sim N(0,1)$ when $x<0$, $X \sim N(0,4)$ when $x>0$, what is E(X)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

I'm reviewing an old problem and I see the solution using a bunch of integrals, but I'm wondering if I missed a more elegant solution.

> If $X \sim N(0,1)$ when $x<0$, $X \sim N(0,4)$ when $x>0$, what is
> E(X)?

For instance, is there a general solution for $E[X]$ over an interval of the distribution of $X$ is changing (but maybe has known Expected Values)?

Answer (score 0):

What is $x$? And what if $x=0$?

To answer the question, I will assume that $x$ is a random variable (different of $X$), and the probability that $x=0$ is $0$: $P(x=0)=0$. Then

$$
E[X]=E[X1_{\{x>0\}}]+E[X1_{\{x<0\}}]=E[X\vert x>0]P(x>0)+E[X\vert x<0]P(x<0).
$$

Here, the distribution of $X$ given $x>0$ is centred, as well as that of $X$ given $x<0$, hence $E[X]=0$.

Comment: Note: $E[X|X>0]$ is not zero.

Comment: $E[X\vert X>0]$ does not appear here. It is $E[X\vert x>0]$.

Comment: is $x$ not a random variable in your notation?

Comment: Yes it is. And?

Comment: Sorry for asking :-) what is the difference between $x$ and $X$?

Comment: Well, they are two different random variables. We don't have any information on them apart from the fact that the distribution of $X$ can be deduced from the sign of $x$. For example, you could imagine that $x$ is any (almost never zero) random variable, $G\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$, $G'\sim\mathcal N(0,4)$ and $X=G1_{\{x<0\}}+G'1_{\{x>0\}}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear answer.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see any way of avoiding integration.
By integration it turns out that, for N(0, $\sigma^2$) and x>0,
$$ E(X) = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt (2\pi)} $$
Hence, in your question, for x<0
$$ E_1(X) = \frac{-1}{\sqrt(2\pi)} $$
and for x>0
$$ E_2(X) = \frac{2}{\sqrt(2\pi)}$$
and for the combined distribution, E(X) will be the mean of $E_1(X)$ and $E_2(X)$.